# GIT_SSH not working on one of my windows slaves

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Super frustrating because this is working on one of my windows slaves, but not this one- and I cant find any config differences.

On the working slave I see this:

```
[Pipeline] checkout
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository git@bitbucket.org:myteam/myapp.git
 > git init C:\Jenkins\workspace\test-slave123456 # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@bitbucket.org:myteam/myapp.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials mygitcreds
 > git fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:myteam/myapp.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=45
 > git config remote.origin.url git@bitbucket.org:myteam/myapp.git # timeout=10
 > git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git config remote.origin.url git@bitbucket.org:myteam/myapp.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@bitbucket.org:myteam/myapp.git
using GIT_SSH to set credentials mygitcreds
 > git fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:myteam/myapp.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=45
 > git rev-parse "origin/test-slave^{commit}" # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 30f11ef09ab13f73fb9a6b75983e1bf32437f51d (origin/test-slave)
Enabling Git LFS pull
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 30f11ef09ab13f73fb9a6b75983e1bf32437f51d # timeout=45
 > git config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials mygitcreds
 > git lfs pull origin # timeout=45
Commit message: "test slave"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 30f11ef09ab13f73fb9a6b75983e1bf32437f51d # timeout=10
```

But on the failing slave:

```
[Pipeline] checkout
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository git@bitbucket.org:myteam/myapp.git
 > git init C:\Jenkins\workspace\test-slave123456 # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@bitbucket.org:myteam/myapp.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials mygitcreds
 > git fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:myteam/myapp.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=45
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:myteam/myapp.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: gituserfromcredbinding@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Its the same pipeline job, same repo, same creds, and the slave should be configured the same but when I change the agent to point to the other slave it cant clone.

On the working slave all i had to do was install git for windows (turn off windows cred store), install java, and then run the jnlp jar.

Tried to do the same thing on the non working slave so I dont know why that one could be failing.

Comment: I have the exact same issue.   I'm in the process of building out another machine from scratch.   No idea why.   Windows slaves aren't as easy to spin up and clone... was hoping to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Bitbucket is not able to authenticate you on the slave where it is not working.

Reason could be:

1. You have not setup the ssh key for the slave where it is not working
   Or
2. The key which is there is not associated to the account you are
   trying to use.

**If creds etc everything is same, what you can try :**

1.Copy the keys present inside the "known_hosts" file in the working slave.

2.Paste the keys copied in step 1 above into the "known_hosts" file of non-working slave.

**If in case keys are also same in both the slaves try :**

ssh into non-working slave and manually try to clone once. Reason being if you have never used that slave(non-working) earlier then it might ask for : "*The authenticity of host, Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)*"  , for which you have to say Yes, only one time.

Comment: This is an issue with jenkins specifically, the slave and master are supposed to handle this config for you. You are not manually configuring ssh on your slaves.

Answer (score 0):

I change git bash from ver: 2.22.0 to ver:2.12.0 (and I select the 'Enable windows cred store'), the windows slave works again

Comment: The latest version that works for me is [2.16.3](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.16.3.windows.1), with or without credential store enabled, 2.17.0 fails.